# Why cv::VideoCapture doesn't want to open device from started std::thread?

Tags: c++, opencv, pthreads

If i call just function with **cv::VideoCapture capture(0)** it works fine. But if std::thread will call this function it silent crash the application without any error messages. Why so?

My test code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "myclass.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    myclass m;
//    m.run();
    m.start();

    return 0;
}
```

**myclass.hpp**

```
#include <thread>

class myclass
{
public:
    myclass();
    virtual ~myclass();

    void start();
    void run();

private:
    std::thread thread;
};
```

**myclass.cpp**

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "myclass.hpp"

myclass::myclass()
{
}

myclass::~myclass()
{
}

void myclass::run()
{
    cv::VideoCapture capture(0);
    cv::Mat frame;

    while(true)
    {
    capture.read(frame);
    cv::imshow("TEST", frame);
    cv::waitKey(30);
    }
    capture.release();
}

void myclass::start()
{
    thread = std::thread(&myclass::run, this);
    thread.detach();
}
```

OpenCV v3.4.2

Comment: Add infinite loop with sleeping in `main` function or call `join` instead of `detach` in `myclass::start` method. When you call `detach` your `myclass::start` method terminates then `main` function terminates too (after calling `m.start` there is nothing to do, `main` ends). You have two threads, `main` and thread started in `start` method. main thread should wait until your thread in `start` method ends.

Comment: Besides, I would recommend not to interact with UI within a non-UI thread. You should interact with UI in the main thread, and leave processing to other threads.

Comment: I just copy this solution from my old project with boost::asio. It have no join() at all and detach() works perfectly. In the end of main() I call oost::asio::io_service::run() there.

Comment: In `boost::asio::io_service::run()` there is loop of events, and your program hungs there, so your app doesn't terminate after ending `myclass::start` method.